# H1B enter US through Guam

Tags: visas, usa, guam, h1b-visas

I am a Indian Passport holder with a valid H1B Visa. I am travelling from SFO to HKG via HNL and Guam. For my return travel to SFO, I am transiting again via Guam (and HNL).

I want to double check that I can do the above travel. There is rumor that H1B holder cannot enter US through Guam unless you are working in Guam. Will I face any issues in Guam immigration?

Answer (score 4):

I can give you a partial answer anyway. I've taken flights with a stopover in Guam before. Whenever I did it, we never got out of the plane. The crew opened the doors, removed the trash, took on ice etc. The plane was also refueled at the time. The interesting part was the pilot informs you that while the plane is being fueled, you must REMOVE your seat belt. Anyway, my point is we never went through immigration in Guam and the immigration in SFO area is the same one that's used by everyone else.

Comment: The procedure for fueling while passenger on board is a standard procedure, the seat belt off requirement is because the plane is on higher risk of fire while refueling so passengers should remove their seat belts to be ready to move quickly in case of fire. Also doors will be open and some doors might be armed (so slide will be deployed once opened).